# Why do we use functions in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Functions are obviously less verbose to write than entities. But it implies many drawbacks, including:

- No generic keyword equivalent
- Only one output possible

It appears that functions can be called recursively. May it not be the case with entities? If so, is there any good reason to use functions except for aesthetic purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in vhdl make the code easy to maintain and read. generally architectures are very big and while debugging if something is not working you can easily find the problematic function and correct it  and no need to analyse the entire architecture body.

in case of small codes it's useless but in more big machines it makes you better understand if you consider it function wise.

There is no rule for this so all comments are welcome.

in short : the advantage of functions are

- overloading
- operators definition
- overloading of operators therefore
- Better Structure of code

Comment: Dear Arpit,
I do understand the need to structurate the code. But can't we always replace functions by small architectures?

Comment: yep you can!one thing can be done in many ways but whenever we define separate architectures we also think of linking them with other entity or with different configurations but if that is not the case then it's better to use functions.

Comment: Dear Arpit,
We agreed on the fact that functions may always be replaced by small architecture. It is obvisouly less powerful, with for example only one output and no generic keyword. Therefore, my question is more relevant than ever.

Comment: wait generic can be declared in entity only,and one output? you can return more then one if you use procedures.

Comment: Functions are obvisously less powerful*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23107/discussion-between-arpit-and-sdenel)

Comment: A question on this - what should we consider, and how should we decide when choosing between using an entity or function? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Functions can't create hardware directly - they have to exist within an architecture to do so.  There's nothing to stop you putting all your functionality into a `function` (or `procedure`) and then just calling that within a `process` though.

Regarding some of your other points:

- With procedures you *can* have multiple `inout` or `out` parameters.
- Entities *can* recurse... Consider:

  ```
  entity recurse is
      generic (
          depth : integer := 1;
          param : integer := 3);
      port (
          a : in  integer;
          b : out integer);
  end entity recurse;

  architecture a1 of recurse is   
      signal c : integer;
  begin
      c <= a + 1;
      bottom: if depth = param generate
          b <= a + 1;
      end generate bottom;

      mid:if depth /= param generate
          recurse_1: entity work.recurse
              generic map (
                  param => param,
                  depth => depth+1)
              port map (
                  a     => c,
                  b     => b);
      end generate mid;
  end architecture a1;
  ```

Not very useful, but it synthesises and simulates just fine.

- And finally, of course you only use functions for aesthetic purposes (assuming you include maintainability and readability into the definition of aesthetic, which most programming types do in my experience).  You only use enumerated types, entities, records and a whole host of other language features for 'aesthetic purposes'.  Even assembly mnemonics are aesthetic!  Maybe should return to toggling DIP switches :)

Comment: @zplesivcak: thanks for the edit - I hadn't noticed I'd messed up the formatting!

Answer (score 5):

I can see why you are confused, another good question would be why there's both *procedure* and *function*. (VHDL seems quite inelegant sometimes!)

That being said, I use both procedures and functions all the time, although mostly in testbenches. For example, for a testbench for a firewall system I made a while back I wrote a procedure called `pd_tb_send_udp_packet()` that I use repeatedly in the main process, e.g.,

```
pd_tb_send_udp_packet("10.10.10.2", 1234, false);
pd_tb_send_udp_packet("10.10.10.1", 1234, true);
pd_tb_send_udp_packet("10.10.10.1", 1235, false);
pd_tb_send_udp_packet("ff02:100::1", 1234, false);
pd_tb_send_udp_packet("ff02:101::1", 1234, true);
```

This procedure generates a random UDP packet with the given addr/port and sends it to the firewall system, then tests whether it is forwarded or not based on the final boolean parameter. Here are the first lines of it, where I use functions from a library:

```
if f_atvtb_is_ipv6_addr(dest_ip_addr) then
  v_ipv6 := true;
  v_ipv6_addr := f_atvtb_ipv6_addr(dest_ip_addr);
else
  v_ipv6 := false;
  v_ipv4_addr := f_atvtb_ip_addr(dest_ip_addr);
end if;
```

The latter two return 128 and 32 bit std_logic_vectors from the string input, respectively.

While I could probably do all this without using procedures and functions somehow, it would definitely be a lot more messy.